# Insertar 1000 registros en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Me gustaría insertar 1000 registros en una tabla para ver cuánto tardar en generar mi CSV.

¿Hay alguna manera de que lo genere automáticamente?.

He buscado y he encontrado `generate_series()`, pero esto me puede crear campos que no existen en otras tablas que deberían existir.

Comment: Si compartes el esquema de la tabla (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <tu tabla>`) o pones un ejemplo de un único `INSERT` podría enseñarte a generar más a partir de él.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes realizar el trabajo mediante un procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE generar()
BEGIN
  DECLARE num INT DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE num <= 1000 DO
    INSERT INTO tabla (...) VALUES (...);
    SET num = num + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Luego bastaría con llamar al procedimiento tantas veces como necesites:

```
CALL generar();
```